# Recursion exercise

Tags: java, recursion

I'm new to Java and doing an exercise on recursion. I found this site and I could really use help breaking this down and explaining how this problem would be solved. Does this require the array to be split or can it be solved in another way?

> The lines included so far are as follows:
>
> ```
> public class RecursionUtils extends Object {
> public static final int findMaxRecursively(List<Integer> numbers) {
>
>     return 0;
> ```
>
> The following is needed in order to complete the code:
>
> 1. findMaxRecursively
> 2. Takes a list of numbers and finds the largest among them using recursive calls.
>
> @param numbers a list of numbers, can be odd or even numbered
>
> @return the largest number in the list.
>
> Hint: Your base case may be a comparison of 2 numbers. The return
>   value must also change.

Any help would be appreciated so I can better understand recursion.

Comment: Nothing in my exercise notes talked about splitting up the array so I'm still confused. Is that the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: Recursion is basically breaking down the problem into smaller sets of the similar type. So, in your case, it effectively means to find the maximum within a smaller set of the array and then using that result to find the max in the entire array.

Comment: Hi @JohnL, you are right. I have added a solution.. Please go through it and see if it helps. I can explain more if you require so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private static final int findMaxRecursively(List<Integer> numbers, int index, int max) {
    return index >= numbers.size()
        ? max
        : findMaxRecursively(numbers, index + 1, Math.max(numbers.get(index), max));
}

public static final int findMaxRecursively(List<Integer> numbers) {
    return findMaxRecursively(numbers, 0, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3);
    System.out.printf("Max is %d in %s%n", findMaxRecursively(numbers), numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecursionUtils extends Object {

    public static final int findMaxRecursively(List<Integer> numbers) {
        if (numbers.size() > 0) {// terminating condition... if there are no
                                    // elements remaining in the list then
                                    // return 0..
            int num1 = numbers.remove(0); // remove the first element of the
                                            // list, thus in the process we
                                            // truncate the list by one element.
            int num2 = findMaxRecursively(numbers); // find the max from the
                                                    // rest of the list..

            return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
        } else
            return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
        numbers.addAll(Arrays
                .asList(new Integer[] { -1, -2, -3, 0, 6, 5, 3, 2 }));
        System.out.println("The entered list is :");
        System.out.println(numbers);
        System.out.println("\nThe max element is : "
                + findMaxRecursively(numbers));
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. This certainly helps me better understand this concept. Thank you

Comment: Pretty sure `LinkedList` has a higher overhead for reamoving items than most other `List`s. Might want to change that for large inputs.

Comment: @M.Shaw I am aware of two types of list ArrayList and LnkedList and think that ---  If we only have to add or remove items at end of list, then use ArrayList.
Otherwise, if removing or adding items elsewhere in the list then we should use LinkedList because in ArrayList all the indices will have to be updated.   If I am missing something please let me know.

Comment: @user403348255 Adding/removing at the end of an `ArrayList` is faster than anything in the `LinkedList`. Adding an object in `LinkedList` requires changing 4 pointers (as `java.utils.LinkedList` is a doubly-linked list), creating an `Entry<T>`. `ArrayLists` just assign values and the memory allocation overhead is very minimal (double allocated size when capacity full).